# trouble loading any OS's

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, grub

I am having some problem installing OS's. I don't have any OS running on my laptop right now. I recently deleted all my partitions and data on the hard drive. Now i want to install windows 7. but while installing from a CD, it says error 0x80070017 exists. So as a remedy, I copied my data  from the cd to a usb drive and tried to boot from it. This time it said "Boot error" and sometimes "grub error".
what to do now?
I am really confused what to do?

Comment: If your unable to install any OS on the drive that normally means the drive is failing.

Answer (score 1):

> The error 0x80070017 translates to "CRC Error" which means that the
>   files that are being copied from the disk are not making it to the
>   hard drive with the same structure, meaning that the "original" files
>   on the disk are being modified/changed/corrupted while being copied to
>   the "destination" location on your hard drive during the install.

Try using another DVD drive if one is available.

Or as you have tried, a USB. Here are instructions for [Installing Win7 using a USB Stick](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/video/installing-win7-using-a-usb-stick). Make sure you've done it correctly.

[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-installation-error-code-0x80070017/2ea19373-2b4a-47e7-8584-04c6966589c3)

Answer (score 0):

0x80070017 usually refers to bad media. It's possible the disc is scratched or if you used an ISO, it was corrupted when it was burnt to disc. I would re-download the ISO and burn it again to see if that fixes the issue.

The reason it wouldn't work when you copied to your flash drive is because the data is corrupted, and corrupted data is corrupted data no matter where you copy it to.